# What type of statistics is Probability?

Tags: probability, random-variable, stochastic-processes

Are probability, random-variable, and stochastic process part of descriptive statistics or inferential statistics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *neither*. Probability theory and statistics are related, but distinct fields. Using the definitions from  Encyclopædia Britannica:

> Probability theory, a branch of mathematics concerned with the
> analysis of random phenomena. [...]

and

> Statistics, the science of collecting, analyzing, presenting, and
> interpreting data. [...]

As you can see, probability theory is a branch of mathematics, concerned with *abstract* concepts like random variables, while statistics is an *applied* field related to analyzing data, where in many cases statistics uses probability theory, but it uses as well other branches of mathematics as well, e.g. calculus, matrix algebra etc.

Comment: There is also mathematical statistics, a sub-field which is concerned with making mathematical statements about statistical concepts. For example, uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimators, best linear unbiased estimation, sufficiency, ancillarity,etc. these concepts would fall under mathematical statistics under most statistician's ontology.

Comment: @LucasRoberts agree, but it is still about data-related concepts.

Comment: Indeed. As David Williams mischievously says in the preface to his book _Weighing the Odds: A Course in Probability and Statistics,_ (Cambridge University Press, 2001), "Probability and Statistics used to be married; then they separated; then they got divorced; now they hardly ever see each other."